# How can I remove duplicate XML nodes using Ruby?

Tags: xml, ruby

Suppose I have this structure:

```
<one>
   <two>
     <three>3</three>
   </two>

   <two>
     <three>4</three>
   </two>

   <two>
     <three>3</three>
   </two>
</one>
```

Is there anyway of getting to this :

```
<one>
  <two>
    <three>3</three>
  </two>

  <two>
    <three>4</three>
  </two>

</one>
```

using Ruby's libraries? I managed to get [this](http://ssscripting.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/remove-duplicate-xml-nodes-using-nokogiri/) using Nokogiri. From my tests, it appears to work, but maybe there's another approach, a better one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about one that does the whole thing in two lines?

```
seen = Hash.new(0)
node.traverse {|n| n.unlink if (seen[n.to_xml] += 1) > 1}
```

If there's a possibility of the same node appearing under two different parents, and you *don't* want those to be considered duplicates, you can change that second line to:

```
node.traverse {|n| n.unlink if (seen[(n.parent.path rescue "") + n.to_xml] += 1) > 1}
```

Comment: Would you please paste the whole suggested solution?

Comment: Great solution! Seems I overthinked mine :D

Comment: That is the whole solution. Other than requiring Nokogiri and setting node=Nokogiri::XML(data), as in his example code.

Comment: Initially, I thought that what you posted was some kind of pseudocode. Then I ran it, and it worked great. Knowing your libs definitely pays off in the long run. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This page explains XML parsing in Ruby a little bit http://developer.yahoo.com/ruby/ruby-xml.html

This page explains some of the reasons why you want to use a proper parser over something like regular expressions:
http://htmlparsing.icenine.ca

At a glance, the approach you're using doesn't seem horrible.

Comment: I'm using an XML parser here. Nokogiri.

Comment: Yea, I haven't ever used Nokogiri.  I was meaning this answer to be more of a way to provide suggestions about other parsers I've actually heard of.  I included the htmlparsing web site out of force of habit.  I answer way too many markup parsing questions every day on IRC.  Sorry. :)